# What em can do which can't be done by %?

Tags: css, xhtml, mobile-website

What `em` can do which can't be done by `%`?

Comment: Is this a trick question?  :-)  Give a dimension in `em` s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each offers a different way of determining a value, and each has certain advantages/disadvantages. These also vary depending on the particular property in question.

For font-sizing, there's little to differentiate the two: both will size the font relative to its parent's font, and both use the same value (<number>) so should be equally precise.

For other properties, such as width, the difference is very significant. Percentage values effectively provide the ability to vary according to window size. Em-based values allow you to vary dimensions according to font-size. The former is great for handling a range of output devices. The latter is great at maintaining consistent line lengths.

Comment: so em is better than % for mobile devices.

Comment: Most current mobile devices tend to 'fix' wide layouts anyway, although I don't know the full details, so I'd advise testing. Percent for layouts is probably better for maximum cross-browser compatibility,

Comment: i'm asking in terms of text sizing

Comment: shouldn't make a difference, then

Answer (score 3):

Ems are useful because they're very high precision and directly related to the font size.

Check out the always-insightful [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/) for some good advice.